# How to communicate with other software from my onscreen keyboard?

Tags: c#, java, api, textbox, on-screen-keyboard

I need to make a C# or Java application somewhat like "windows onscreen keyboard". I am not sure how to fill the alphabets into other applications on clicking buttons on my form.
How do I communicate with the focused textbox or textarea on any given windows software, browser etc.?
Any hints or code examples please?

Comment: While I'm not quite sure about this, I believe there is the 'Virtual Keystroke' method, which you can send to the OS. Basically your application would generate keystrokes corresponding to the clicked button.

Comment: [inter-process communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an informative video on youtube about this very subject:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgFXwWQwE9k

And this is the source: http://pastebin.com/drWY3qnz